# Username password Macro or tool

Tags: macros, automation

I write extensions for a program. The program has a username/password dialogue box.  There is no "remember my password" option. The task of entering this information is quite cumbersome and breaks my development workflow.

Is there a tool that will automate this process?

Ideally, I would like the tool to launch the program > type in my username and password > click Ok to login.

A subset of this functionality would be better than nothing. I have visual studio 2010.

The program is a custom medical application with very little documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will be perfect for this. I actually already use it for something similar.

Your script will look something like this:

```
;This macro will run when you press Windows + a
#a::
Run, [program executable]
;You may need to uncomment this pause and set it if your program doesn't start instantly.
;pause [number in milliseconds]
Send [username]{tab}[password]{enter}
return
```

Note that this may be different if your dialog box is strange, I've set this up for the standard username/password dialog.

Comment: Great tool.  My script is similar.  I chose WinWaitActive over pause to wait for window to become active.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Ah, didn't know about that one. The only thing I'd be worried about would be if the program didn't immediately open the password dialog after becoming active.

Comment: I havent had any issues even with a slow UI load.